# How did the Ancient Greek gears look like (identify this)

Tags: antiquity

I've noticed these gear-like Ancient Greek items in a local museum annotated along the lines of "decorative clothing pins". These don't look like much decorative to me (too symmetric for their liking?), rather they look suspiciously like gears. They also have a small hole in the middle, through where they could be attached to a shaft.

[image: gears or pins?]

To generalize this question - how did the gears used in Antikythera look like? What were the basic ways in which they were coupled, how many teeth did they have, how did they produce the rotation angle difference required?

Quick googling showed modern gears which look like reconstruction of how Antikythera looked like, as well as the same worn out gear, which nontheless looks like what I've showed above.

The bottom item is also of interest since it seems to contain the endings of four shafts. Could it be a part of a mechanism?

Comment: The museum items pictured would not work well as gears. Gears need to have even teeth spacing and those appear way too fragile. The gears of the Antikythera mechanism had triangular teeth, which is subpar to modern gear teeth profiles.

Comment: [Nature's article](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-84310-w) on the Antikythera mechanism has detailed images of its reconstructions, including the gears and their couplings. They look nothing like the OP images.

Comment: They do look somewhat like the Mars and Venus secondary gears. Not the main gear to be sure.